# Cannot retrieve image link from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, image

So i got this problem occurred, i want to retrieve image from database which is NOT a blob and i use image_link and it linked with my folder `"images/"`

For example:

`"images/Banner1_1.png" << id=1`

`"images/Banner1_2.png" << id=2`

`"images/Banner1_3.png" << id=3`

and all this links are inside my database.

So what i want to do here is, i have html code where i want the picture to be appeared on this page using specified ID for example:

**index.html**

```
<img src="get.php?id=1" />
<img src="get.php?id=2" />
<img src="get.php?id=3" />
```

**get.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("aliquantum") or die(mysql_error()) ;
$id = $_GET['id'];

if(!isset($id) || empty($id) || !is_int($id)){
    die("Please select your image!");
}else{
$sql = "SELECT image_link FROM images WHERE id='".$id."'";
$url = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($url);
$link= '.$row['image_link'].';
echo $link;
}
?>
```

But it didnt show anything or just broken image icon appeared.

Comment: Insert error reporting to get more information: http://php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php . Also note that mysql_* is deprecated. Third: a user without a password is unsafe!

Comment: You need to retrieve the image links from your database and insert them into your page before you send the page to the browser. What you have in `index.html` will attempt to load the image, not the URL.

Comment: have checked how the image path it is ?

Comment: It is **NOT** a very good idea to use root in your PHP scripts for accessing your database. root can do anything - instead create a user that has just enough permissions to do the job. Protects your database against silly mistakes etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Is bad idea to store image_link in a database, but since you've already made the decision to do so, lets take a look at accomplishing the displaying of the image.

First: `(create any function for retrieve image and include in your index page.)`

```
<?PHP
   function images($id)
    {   //please Secure your ID using int() or is_numeric ....

     $sql="select image_link from images where id=$id";

       $rs=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

       $row =mysql_fetch_array($rs,MYSQL_BOTH);

     $data = $row[0];

   echo '<img src="images/'.$data.'">';
   }
?>
```

now for display `(after include function)` :

```
<?PHP
    echo images('1'); // your dynamic id
?>
```

Now This Worked!

Comment: i'm not storing it into database.. just the link of folder of the images.. so now i just want to retrieve the link and use it in my HTML code.. because it's not possible to manually assign everything using <img src="">

Comment: DAMN! It works perfectly! Thank you very much.. appreciate it! i'm happy there are bunch of people around here are willingly to help me.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options here:

1) Stream the images through get.php, like you try to do now, but the output returned by get.php is not correct. It should return:

```
$location='/location/to/image.gif';
$size = getimagesize($location);
$img_type = $size['mime'];
$data = file_get_contents($location);
$img_data = addslashes($data);
header("Content-type: ".$img_type);
print $img_data;
```

2) Get the image name/path using javascript and set the src of your img tag to point to the file on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `php`, but what i see is that you are returning the image itself

```
$link='<img src= "'.$row['image_link'].'">';
```

I guess you just need to return the url.

```
$link='.$row['image_link'].';
```

Comment: Can you inspect the DOM and show exactly what are you getting as the output of `<img src="get.php?id=1" />`

Answer (score 0):

The way you are echoing link is the problem. It should be 
`$link=$row['image_link'];`

If this is not working, then you also have to check the path to be sure that just using the path from the db would get the file. It could be you need to add something to the path you have

Answer (score -2):

What you need is not really PHP it is a library inside PHP called GD library it is a really wide used library used in creating captcha , protecting emails , scalling images(see bellow for links on how to do those stuffs)

For your needs it is really simple and easy to use here is a link to start up:

http://www.oxxus.net/tutorials/php/gd-library

http://php.about.com/od/gdlibrary/Graphics_GD_Library.htm

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/php/phpgd/

how to enable GD library:

http://www.webassist.com/tutorials/Enabling-the-GD-library-setting

first try if you failed come here and I I'll help you.

introduction:

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=156

protecting emails:

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=157

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=158

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=159

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=160

watermarks:

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=161

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=162

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=163

captcha:

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=163

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=165

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=166

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=167

ScalingDown:

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=168

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=169

http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=170